# PHP BBCode related issue. How to get values between two tags?

Tags: php, function, replace, bbcode

I need to do the following for my website.

```
$comment = "[item]Infinity Edge[/item]<br>[item]Eggnog Health Potion[/item]";
$this->site->bbcode->postBBCode($comment);
```

The BBCode function is like this:

```
function postBBCode($string)
{
            $string = nl2br($string);
            $string = strip_tags($string, '<br></br>');
            $string = $this->tagItem($string);
            return $string;
}

function tagItem($string)
{
     //Get all values between [item] and [/item] values
     //Appoint them to an array.
     //foreach item_name in array, call convertItems($item_name) function.
     //Now, each item_name in array will be replaced with whatever  convertItems($item_name) function returns.
     //return modified string
}

function convertItems($itemName)
{
    // -- I already made this function, but let me explain what it does.
    //Query the database with $itemName.
    //Get item_image from database.
    //Return '<img src="$row['item_image']></img>';
}
```

Okay, I already asked my questions between functions. I hope you understood what I am trying to do.

Basically, anything between [item] and [/item] tags will be converted into an image, but the image path of each items will be taken from database.

The part I am having hard times is getting values between [item] and [/item] tags correctly. It should be getting all the correct matches it finds, not the first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a preg_match_all on $string, you'll get a result set with all the matches:

```
    $results = array();
preg_match_all('#\[item\](.*?)\[\/item\]#', $string, $results);
```

$results will have an array of results that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [item]Infinity Edge[/item]
            [1] => [item]Eggnog Health Potion[/item]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Infinity Edge
            [1] => Eggnog Health Potion
        )

)
```

Now you should be able to loop through the $results[1] and send it through convertItems.

Comment: Thank you. By the way how should I be replacing the values? By using str_replace or preg_replace_callback instead? Which one would be more efficient way of doing and give better performance?

Comment: My preferred way of doing the replace would be the preg_replace_callback. It makes processing the text a lot easier since str_replace would have to be called individually for each instance and preg_replace_callback would only have to be called once.

preg_replace_callback could also be used instead of preg_match_all if you already have your text to replace before processing.