# How to make PHP BB Codes with RegExp?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, bbcode

for my website, I want a simple BB code system. Nothing special--just hyperlinks and images will be fine for now.

I'm not good with RegExp. Period. But if someone could show me an example, I may be able to grasp it to clone it into different tags.

Your help is very appreciated!

Comment: Example using the search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737846/php-bbcode-related-issue-how-to-get-values-between-two-tags

Comment: Please explain down votes.
Downvoting this question tells nothing.
(I beleive the approprate answer is< "Don't use Regex for parsing because *BBCOde is not a regular langues, *Regex is hard to maintain. instead use `X`"
BUt not one has given it, they have just downvoted.
---
Aso I suspect this is a duplicate post 
(No vote)

Comment: I think the downvotes are as a result of the question not showing any prior research - we like prior effort here! That said, if you do a web search for _Markdown PHP_ you'll find a library that will do this for you, ready-made `:)`.

Comment: I've tried looking up PHP RegExp before, but all I see are lists of delimeters, and then a bunch of huge expressions that just seem a bit to hard for beginners like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user asked for something simple, so I gave him something simple.

```php
$input = "[link=http://www.google.com]test[/link]";
$replacement = preg_replace('/\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/link\]/', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $input);
```

Where `/\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/link\]/` is the regex, `<a href="$1">$2</a>` is the format, `$input` is the input/data, and `$replacement` is the return.

Comment: If you're using PHP4+, the `$n` notation is preferred over the `\\n` -- see [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 4):

I have to imagine this exists out there for free somewhere, but here's how I'd do it.

```
// Patterns
$pat = array();
$pat[] = '/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/';         // URL Type 1
$pat[] = '/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/';   // URL Type 2
$pat[] = '/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/';         // Image
// ... more search patterns here

// Replacements
$rep = array();
$rep[] = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';             // URL Type 1
$rep[] = '<a href="$1">$2</a>';             // URL Type 2
$rep[] = '<img src="$1" />';                // Image
// ... and the corresponding replacement patterns here


// Run tests
foreach($DIRTY as $dirty)
{
    $clean = preg_replace($pat, $rep, $dirty);

    printf("D: %s\n", $dirty);
    printf("C: %s\n", $clean);
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output:**

```
D: Before [url]http://www.stackoverflow.com[/url] after
C: Before <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a> after

D: Before [url]http://www.stackoverflow.com[/url] [url]http://www.google.com[/url] after
C: Before <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a> <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> after

D: Before [url=http://www.stackoverflow.com]StackOverflow[/url]
C: Before <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>

D: Before [img]https://www.google.com/logos/2012/haring-12-hp.png[/img] after
C: Before <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2012/haring-12-hp.png" /> after
```

For each `$pat` pattern element you add, you need to add a `$rep` element.  The `$DIRTY` array is just a list of test cases and can be any length you think is sufficient.

The important parts here, and the parts that you would use are the `$pat` and `$rep` arrays and the `preg_replace()` function.

Comment: Daedalus is more on the ball with what I had in mind--I've seen a friend of mine do it in about a few lines like that, though your method seems interesting to try. Thanks!

Comment: lol sigh, less lines != better -- especially in this case -- but good luck sir.

Comment: Also, this is how you would convert both of the standard BBCode types of `[url]` tags as well as `[img]` tags.