# How do I write an simple BB-Code-like regex expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, expression, bbcode

For example:
My phrases are `[$IMAGE ID="1"]`, `[$URL ID="1"]` or `[$SIGNATURE]` (without ID)

How can I get each the `NAME` after `$` and optional the ID after `ID="`?
And how do I replace each `NAMEPLACEHOLDER` (with ID) with my `replaceNAMEPLACEHOLDER($id)` function?

Comment: Question duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458103/how-to-make-php-bb-codes-with-regexp

Comment: Not really. This is not a typical BB-Code.

Comment: You want to catch the "$" to "="?

Comment: No, I actually just used $ in front of the NAME as unique identification because my content may contain [pla pla pla] so I don't want to replace [pla pla pla], just [$NAME] or [$NAME ID="1"]. but I need to get the ID of $NAME

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to replace? Post a example.

Comment: _“Not really. This is not a typical BB-Code.”_ – it’s still “typical”, simple regex. So if you don’t have any basic knowledge about those, go get some first.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It might be not duplicated but the first "duplicated" link was helpful enough for me. Thanks!